# Add Text Information to Different XML Element each time information is submitted c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file that collects information with Button_Click, so it starts off empty.

**XML Sample**

```
<marina>
<dockone>
</dockone>
<docktwo>
</docktwo>
</marina>
```

When I submit information from a textbox, a new XmlNode  is created called *slipone*, and another XmlNode called *reg* is nested within that.

**XML Sample 2**

```
<marina>
<dockone>
<slipone>
<reg>12345</reg>
<slipone>
</dockone>
<docktwo>

</docktwo>
</marina>
```

I have attempted to create an if/else statement that will add a new XmlNode called *sliptwo*, with *reg* still nested within it, if *slipone* already has text, like so:

```
<marina>
<dockone>
<slipone>
<reg>12345</reg>
<slipone>
<sliptwo>
<reg>67890</reg>
<sliptwo>
</dockone>
<docktwo>
</docktwo>
</marina>
```

However the closest I have gotten is another XMlnode is still created, however it labels itself as *slipone*, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
 <marina>
<dockone>
<slipone>
<reg>12345</reg>
<slipone>
<slipone>
<reg>67890</reg>
<slipone>
</dockone>
<docktwo>
</docktwo>
</marina>
```

This is an example of what I have been playing around with. Ignore the operators as I have resorted to trial and error but still have gotten nowhere. Please help!

C# Example

```
XmlDocument XmlDocObj1 = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDocObj1.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/SlipData.xml"));
        XmlNode rootnode1 = XmlDocObj1.SelectSingleNode("marina/dockone");
        XmlNode dockone = rootnode1.AppendChild(XmlDocObj1.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "slipone", ""));
        XmlNode docktwo = rootnode1.AppendChild(XmlDocObj1.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "sliptwo", ""));
        XmlNode dockthree = rootnode1.AppendChild(XmlDocObj1.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "slipthree", ""));




            if (regfinal.Text != dockone.InnerText)
            {

                dockone.AppendChild(XmlDocObj1.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Reg", "")).InnerText = regfinal.Text;
                XmlDocObj1.Save(Server.MapPath("/App_Data/SlipData.xml"));
            }

        else if (regfinal.Text == dockone.InnerText)
            {

                docktwo.AppendChild(XmlDocObj1.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Reg", "")).InnerText = regfinal.Text;
                XmlDocObj1.Save(Server.MapPath("/App_Data/SlipData.xml"));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic isn't going to do what I think you are saying since the only time (regfinal.Text != dockone.InnerText) will evaluate to false is when you enter nothing in your text control.

I believe you might mean to say if dockone exists then create another node called docktwo. This will require you to change your logic.

Some very simple code to get you a bit farther down the path. Not intended to be perfect or solve all problems...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument XmlDocObj1 = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDocObj1.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString()+"test.xml");
        XmlNode rootnode1 = XmlDocObj1.SelectSingleNode("marina/dockone");
        XmlNode dockone = rootnode1.AppendChild(XmlDocObj1.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "slipone", ""));
        XmlNode docktwo = rootnode1.AppendChild(XmlDocObj1.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "sliptwo", ""));
        XmlNode dockthree = rootnode1.AppendChild(XmlDocObj1.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "slipthree", ""));

        //jsh: old logic
        //if (textBox1.Text != dockone.InnerText)

        //new logic to test whether we have already created the dockone node which should only occur once
        //you already have the logic for selecting the dockone node above...now just test if you already have it.
        //NOTE: you may actually want a switch statement given that you avhe dockone, docktwo, and dockthree or at least another 
        //      if statement to see if docktwo has been created and thus creaste dockthree.
        if (rootnode1 == null )
        {
            dockone.AppendChild(XmlDocObj1.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Reg", "")).InnerText = textBox1.Text;
            XmlDocObj1.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "test.xml");
        }
        //else if (textBox1.Text == dockone.InnerText) jsh: old logic
        else
        {
            docktwo.AppendChild(XmlDocObj1.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Reg", "")).InnerText = textBox1.Text;
            XmlDocObj1.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "test.xml");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want to do however I have no clue how to construct that
I am quite new to c# so I'm learning on the go

Comment: Alright. I will add a simple snippet of code tonight.

Comment: btw, that snippet is from a windows forms project.